# Unauthorized access while copying files onto USB via OTG Xamarin Android

Tags: usb-otg

I am writing a code to paste files onto the USB Sandisk pen drive connected to my android KitKat device using an **OTG** cable.

I am using the following code snippet.

Using the following code I get a popup asking permission and on allowing it the *mUsbManager.HasPermission(device)*; returns true, but while i copy the file I get an Unauthorized access exception.

I have set the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission.

> //Code Snippet

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)_mainActivity.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
var deviceList = manager.DeviceList;
IEnumerable deviceIterator = deviceList.Values.AsEnumerable();

if (deviceIterator.Count() > 0)
{
var device = deviceIterator.ElementAt(0);

ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
var mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(_mainActivity.ApplicationContext, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);

UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager)_mainActivity.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
mUsbManager.RequestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

bool perm = mUsbManager.HasPermission(device);
if (perm)
{
    string FileNameSource = "/storage/emulated/0/FileNotPresent.txt";
    string FileNameDestination = "/storage/2A85-5687/FileNotPresent.txt"; 

    File.Copy(FileNameSource, FileNameDestination);
}
}
```

Second question how can i get the path for the connected USB that as of now i have hard coded into the **FileNameDestination** variable.

A sample code snippet will really be helpful. Thanks.